# Names for complement of the union and intersection of two sets.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology

What is a good name for $ (A \cup B)^c $ or the *complement of the union* of two sets?
Not union?  NOR?  Union complement?

And what is a good name for $ (A \cap B)^c $ or the *complement of the intersection* of two sets?
Not intersection?   NAND? Intersection complement?

Comment: You could simplify the former to "The intersection of the complements" and the latter to "The union of the complements" - but there's no need to name everything.

Comment: @Meelo - Aside from the fact that you (like i before i fixed the Q) have them reversed, you are not actually *simplifying* the description, merely providing another permutation. Appreciated nonetheless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $ (A \cup B)^c =  A^{c} \cap B^c $ and $ (A \cap B)^c =  A^{c} \cup B^c $, I'd say "complements intersection" and "complements union", respectively. There's no proper term though.

Answer (score 2):

NOR is usually $(A\cup B)^c$. NAND usually means $(A\cap B)^c$.

NAND and NOR are more commonly used for binary operations, particularly talking about logic gates, but they extend to set definitions.

The expression $A\cup B$ is the union, and thus is "OR" - the elements of $A\cup B$ are either elements of $A$ OR elements of $B$. The elements of $(A\cup B)^c$ are thus neither elements of $A$ NOR elemenents of $B$.

NAND and NOR are interesting in that everything can be defined in terms of them.

For example, if you have $A\star B$ defined as NOR, then $$\begin{align}A^c=&A\star A
\\A\cap B&=A^c\star B^c = (A\star A)\star(B\star B)\\
A\cup B&=(A^c \cap B^c)^c =\text{ something horrific}
\end{align}$$

The fundamental disadvantage of NAND and NOR is the lack of associativity.

Comment: I wondered why you were initially "merely" restating my question -- until i realized my serious typo, NAND - NOR reversal, now fixed, in the question ;-)